# HornetQ Consumers on Linux High CPU Load

Tags: java, jms, netty, nio, hornetq

We are using HornetQ 2.2.14 on CentOS 6.3.  We have been experiencing an issue with high CPU usage in our appservers, and have narrowed it down to our HornetQ Consumers using a profiler.

Specifically, we are calling this method in rapid succession on empty queues with approximately 150 consumers:

```
// Called about every 10ms per consumer.
javax.jms.MessageConsumer.receive(10);
```

This results in about 2 NIO worker threads tracing back to Netty, consuming about 50% of 2 CPU cores, on our otherwise idle Tomcat instances.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
21939 tomcat    20   0 9061m 1.6g  16m R 55.4 21.2   1:06.88 java
21777 tomcat    20   0 9061m 1.6g  16m S 47.6 21.2   1:29.40 java
21777 tomcat    20   0 9061m 1.6g  16m S  7.3 21.2   1:33.41 java
21763 tomcat    20   0 9061m 1.6g  16m S  6.6 21.2   1:28.84 java
21682 tomcat    20   0 9061m 1.6g  16m S  4.3 21.2   0:26.70 java
```

The thing is, using the exact same code and Tomcat configuration on Windows, the CPU cores are idle.  This leads me to believe this is a Linux/Netty/HornetQ issue.  Has anyone else seen this before, and if so, how do I make it go away?

Linux Version: CentOS 6.3 x64
Linux Kernel Version:  Linux version 2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.x86_64

Here are the 2 Java versions I have tested with same results:

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_10-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_38-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.13-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Forgot to add, here are the hot spots identified by the profiler:
org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.receive() and
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select()

Comment: Switching HornetQ to use blocking IO via <param key="use-nio" value="false" /> has no affect.  Now instead of 2 NIO worker threads consuming CPU, I get 2 blocking IO worker threads consuming the same amount of CPU.  One client thread, and one server thread.

Comment: What happens if you increase the timeout value to, say 30ms. I ask because there could be something unexpected happening if the timeout value is close to the resolution of the real-time clock, and I recall clocks operating right around that 10ms level.

Comment: The CPU usage seems to be directly proportional to the timeout value.  If I lower the timeout, or use ClientConsumerImpl.receiveNoWait(), the CPU usage goes up even more.  If I increase the timeout to 30ms, the CPU usage drops a little bit, but is still higher than expected.  That is to say it drops from 40% usage to 20% usage.

Comment: Switched HornetQ connection and acceptor factories to use "in VM" instead of Netty just to test and the issue went away.  This has to be an issue with Netty on Linux since it works fine on Windows.

Comment: Consider updating your question with all the information you are putting in the comments.  The comments section is not the right place for this information.

Answer (score 2):

IMO you should use a MessageListener.. or just block for a longer time, like 10 seconds...

...  10 milliseconds repeatedly is a huge burst on your system. Especially that the client will send a callback to the server on every time.

Let the message system to do the work for you, i.e. let it call you when the message arrives. You can't expect anything else if you are polling the system every 10 milliseconds for nothing.

This is the culprit for your issue, as yourself noted:

```
consumer.receive(10);
```

Do the math, each consumer where you are hammering the server with this receive(10) is making the server to send you 100 messages per second per consumer to say... I'm empty.

a receive(10) will make a roundtrip to guarantee there are no messages in transit. So, you are hammering the server with empty messages.

Your application is not supposed to perform well based on the parameters you are forcing it. And that to any message solution that guarantees you a receive(10) is empty before returning null.

Comment: If this is the case, why does the same code work fine on Windows with all CPU cores idling?  I would expect HornetQ to be able to handle a couple hundred consumers concurrently without using a ton of CPU resources.

Comment: The issue is not with HornetQ, you are requesting a new message just for 10 milliseconds and not finishing the loop.
Linux Kernels are known to be better on distributing the tasks, perhaps a more efficient kernel is letting your bad code to have more executions? that's just a guess of course, but your code is broken as it is... and I can assure you that would be an issue with any messaging provider.

Comment: what you're doing would be equivalent to this:
while (true) { db.select(0); wait(10); }

And you're blaming on HornetQ for your CPU waste?

that would waste CPU on any software you use actually.. not just a messaging provider.

Comment: That's hilarious... I give you a correct answer for a bad question and you are giving me a -1 vote....

Anyway: good luck with your infinite loop. while (true) { Sleep(1); ask-nothing; }

YOu are not only wasting your CPU, but other's people time as well

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it was neither correct, nor helpful.  You made far too many wild assumptions about my use case.  I never said I was polling anything.  I actually have a pool of consumers that are used to handle web requests.  A request comes in, and a consumer is grabbed from the pool to check the queue.  This is the reason I cannot wait for 10 seconds like you suggest.  The request must come back almost instantly if there is nothing in the queue.  There is a reason messaging systems have receiveNoWait().  It is not always acceptable to wait so long for a message.

Comment: Also, your assumption about Linux handling more executions is flawed.  My windows dev machine is handling the same number of executions with the same response time.  Only its CPU is almost 100% idle.  So this tells me that it is not unreasonable to expect a messaging system to be able to handle this type of traffic.  Because it does handle it on windows with an idle CPU.  Again, this is a Linux/Netty/HornetQ issue.  And your dismissive attitude contributed absolutely nothing toward figuring out why Linux is having such a hard time with this on a FAR superior server class machine.

Comment: My information is correct... 

If you keep hammering the server to not return anything, you will use CPU. there's no way around. That's why message systems will offer you message listeners.  The fact that you are hammering the system probably also means you are using a message system like a database where something else is storing the data and you keep in a loop. Don't loop...   wait.. use a listener if you can... and that's a correct information...     And I'm not talking about hornetq here.. I'm talking about any messaging solution out there...  Good luck!

Comment: If you were hammering the system under regular circunstances I would take it as an issue. but you are hammering the system to not return you anything.... there's nothing I can do about it.. I can't optimize the system for cases where nothing is being returned... there's simply nothing we can do about it....      receiveNoWait will guarantee a roundtrip on the server... and that will use CPU.

Comment: And lastly... receive(10) will also guarantee a roundtrip to the server...   it will wait 10 seconds.. and if nothing arrived it will perform a receiveNoWait with a roundtrip to the server.

Comment: Clebert is right, i ran into the same issue and followed his advice, the CPU usage on my hornetq machine dropped dramatically. +1

Comment: Thanks: The same advice is valid for any messaging service. I'm not sure why this user didn't accept my answer. I have added a lot of effort into answering it and I ended up with a negative vote from him.

Answer (score 1):

While Clebert's answer is a bit tough to swallow, it is ultimately a valid case.  You can easily create multiple message listeners that will act as your workers and allow the JMS provider to call them.  Assuming that your destination is a queue of some kind, the message listeners will be called with fairly distributed load to allow multiple threads to handle the processing.  Creating message listeners will allow the JMS provider to call them when a message arrives, and not wait for your client to consume the message.

Every time you call the receive method it will behave the way Clebert is describing (and he should know, he's the HornetQ lead).

I'm not sure what version of Netty HornetQ 2.2.14, but I did find a few issues on github in their repos related to something very similar.  Perhaps you can try updating the version of Netty in your application to see if that helps?

https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/592

https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/582